# Deux phrases sans article

Tags: grammaire, usage, absence-d-article

Deux phrases exclamatives; active et passive respectivement.

*Source (p. 15) :*

[La Nouvelle grammaire du français](https://www.amazon.fr/nouvelle-grammaire-du-fran%C3%A7ais/dp/2038000425)

> On a enfin obtenu satisfaction !
>
> Satisfaction est enfin obtenue !

Pourquoi satisfaction est sans article (de la) ? Quand dirait-on **de la satisfaction** ?

Comment: L'absence d'article (ou *article nul*) est une construction très courante : http://gabrielwyler.com/page020.html

Comment: @jlliagre Merci vivement. Oui zero article dans les livres du français destinés aux anglophones. Je voudrais savoir s'il y a une version pdf (ou copie papier à acheter) de la grammaire que tu as mentionnée plusieurs fois (http://gabrielwyler.com/page000.html) ou celle pour des finophonnes (http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/000.html) qui me paraissent complètes et courantes.

Comment: Il y a eu une version papier en 2009, puis une version pdf en 2011 mais depuis, seule la version web en ligne est disponible et mise à jour. c.f. https://jyx.jyu.fi/handle/123456789/37015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pas vraiment une réponse, mais une remarque que les formes *« obtenir satisfaction »*, *« avoir satisfaction »* ou *« donner satisfaction »* [existent](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/satisfaction) sous cette forme figée en français.

On pourrait éventuellement tracer des parallèles avec *« obtenir réparation »* ou *« devoir réparation »*, qui sont aussi communs et s’emploient dans des contextes proches.

Plusieurs autres noms s’emploient aussi communément sans article après un verbe :

- faire pénitence, faire amende honorable *(systématiques)*
- prendre garde *(systématique)*
- assumer gîte et couvert *(parfois **le** gîte et **le** couvert)*
- obtenir dédommagement *(parfois **un** dédommagement)*
- inclure taxes et pourboire *(parfois **les** taxes et **le** pourboire)*
- faire vidange *(d’un véhicule à moteur, parfois **la** ou  **sa** vidange)*
- rendre justice, jouer franc jeu, mettre fin (à qqch), faire route

*etc.*

Comment: Merci pour la réponse !

Comment: @dimitris Merci d'avoir accepté ma contribution comme réponse, mais ainsi que je le mentionne d'entrée de jeu, ce n'est pas vraiment une réponse, simplement quelques observations. L'historique de la forme sans article m'est inconnu, et il serait bien que quelqu'un s'y connaissant davantage en trace les grandes lignes.

Comment: Je vous en prie. Je pense que votre réponse et la référence de @jlliagre (article nul) me suffisent. Bien sur toutes autres réponses sont bienvenues:-)!